# Access APEX Tabular form cell values

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I have master-detail form in APEX 5.0, and I need to insert master and detail data in the same time using PL/SQL.

What I need is to access the tabular form rows to use them in Insert statement.

I greatly appreciate your help!

Best Regards,
Saddam.

Comment: you should describe a little more of the dynamics involved in the process or how do you expect them to work

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
APEX_APPLICATION.G_F0i(j);
// i- column index, j- row index
```